# How to regenerate auth tokens based on conditions in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I'm working on testing some API's (10-15 in number) that uses Bearer token for authentication. The token has an expiration condition post which I have to re-generate the token. I've not worked on this situation on Jmeter so looking for answers how this can be done.

Condition -

- At start of tests, generate the Token
- Use the token in API's for let say 5 users
- If the following conditions are met, re-generate token

  - If the token has been used 50 times
  - If the token timeout period is reached, which is 10 minutes.

As per my understanding, if I am creating 5 threads for the API tests, and passing the Token to these 5 threads, then the first condition gets reached once there are 50 requests made and so I have to re-generate the token mid test and use that again.

Is this achievable in Jmeter? I've see couple of examples where the second condition regarding timeout can be done, but here I have two separate conditions?

OS - Not sure if this needs to be done via Groovy scripting as I have never worked on a groovy script before.

Answer (score 1):

1. When you generate the token use [__time() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__time) to store the token generation time into a JMeter Variable like `${__time(,tokenGenerationTime)}`
2. Depending on the way you design your test either use [__counter()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__counter) function or [Counter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Counter) test element or a pre-defined JMeter variable which holds the current iteration of the [Loop Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Loop_Controller) or [While Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#While_Controller) or [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) iteration to identify how many times the token was used
3. Use [If Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#If_Controller) with [__jexl3() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__jexl3) to compare:

   - current time with the last token generation time
   - current counter value with 50

     ```
     ${__jexl3((${__time(,)} - ${tokenGenerationTime}) > 600000 || ${counter} > 50,)}
     ```

   and if time delta is >= 10 minutes and/or counter is > 50 - call regenerate token action like it's described in the [Easily Write a GOTO Statement in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/easily-write-a-goto-statement-in-jmeter) article